# Using an external stylesheet in my asp classic page, isn't working because of frameset

Tags: html, css, asp-classic

So after 100 times of testing I am about to give up.

**The problem**

I have created a ASP Classic web page which has some functionality in it (obviously). All works fine but for some reason the stylesheet isn't being loaded into the page, but when I paste the CSS directly into my asp page it is working.

**What I have done so far (but didn't worked)**

Alright, so I have tested multiple things which all didn't seem to have any effect. See the list below:

- Added doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` for html 5
- Inserted meta, title, body, html correctly
- Closed my link and meta tags
- Removed the `<style css/text>` in my css stylesheet and saved it as a css file.
- Made sure that the stylesheet and the asp page were in the same folder.
- used a absolute link to the style sheet just to be sure (also tried it without the absolute href).
- Do a page validation on both my asp page (the html) and css stylesheet, which were both validated.
- Tried to change the doctype to html 4 (where font and frameset was allowed)
- Try'd to do it with `@import`
- Try'd to use alternate stylesheet on the rel=, using the title, etc. (which aren't necessary).
- Checked the stylesheet for to many spaces (like: width: 50 px;) or html in it.
- Check the CSS page link directly in the browser (output is OK)

While typing the last list item (the css checking in the browser) I thought about not having done that for the asp page. So what I did is pasting the link in the browser, for some reason if I do this the stylesheet IS being loaded!

**So this probably needs a bit of more information about where the web page is being loaded.**

The specific web page is part of a website which obviously contains multiple web pages. The website which contains the web page is however not created by me. 
The website is using, for some reasson, a `FRAMESET`. So the website has a menu to the left and one of the menu links is the link to my webpage, which is called like so: `http://MYWebsite.com/MyPage.asp?action=mypage`

The action is used in my asp code in my webpage.

Though, when clicking the link, and going to the page, the link changes into `http://MYWebsite.com/frameset.asp` (when I am on my page).

So my guess is that the use of the frameset is messing up my stylesheet linking..

But what to do about it?

**The (ASP PAGE) code:**

```
<!--#include file="tools.asp"-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ops.van-hulten.com/StyleVoorraadlijst.css"></link>



    <title>Voorraadlijst</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    function enable_cb() {
      if (this.checked) {
        $("input.StyleOmschrijving").removeAttr("disabled");

      } else {
        $("input.StyleOmschrijving").attr("disabled", true);
      }
    }

    ;$(function() {
      enable_cb2();
      $("#InkoopEnable").click(enable_cb2);
    });

    function enable_cb2() {
      if (this.checked) {
        $("input.StyleInkoopbedrag").removeAttr("disabled");

      } else {
        $("input.StyleInkoopbedrag").attr("disabled", true);
      }
    }

    </script>


    </head>

    <% 
    if request.querystring("action")="voorraadlijst" then
    %>
    <body>
    <h2 align="left"><font face="Verdana, Arial" color="#000080">Voorraadlijst</font></h2>

    <br>

    <%
        openconn con

        sSQL="SELECT * FROM qryVoorraadlijst ORDER BY status ASC, omschrijving ASC"
        set rst=con.execute(sSQL)

    %>


    <TABLE>
    <tr bgcolor="#0080C0">
    <th><font color="white" face="Verdana, Arial" size=2>Datum</th>
    <th><font color="white" face="Verdana, Arial" size=2>OrderNr</th>
    <th><font color="white" face="Verdana, Arial" size=2>Eindklant</th>
    <th><font color="white" face="Verdana, Arial" size=2>Aantal</th>
    <th><font class="hoverEffect" title="Hier kan het aantal worden veranderd" color="white" face="Verdana, Arial" size=2>Aantal veranderen</th>
    <th width=350><font color="white" face="Verdana, Arial" size=2>Omschrijving<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_oms" id="OmschrijvingEnable" style="float: right;"></th>
    <th width=125><font color="white" face="Verdana, Arial" size=2>Inkoopbedrag<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_ink" id="InkoopEnable" style="float: right;"></th>
    <th width=125><font color="white" face="Verdana, Arial" size=2>Totaalbedrag</th>    
    <th><font class="hoverEffect" title="Wanneer voor de status 'Binnen' is gekozen en op OK wordt gedrukt zal het voorraad product worden doorgeboekt naar de bestellijst en hier verdwijnen" color="white" face="Verdana, Arial" size=2>Status</th>
    <th><font color="white" face="Verdana, Arial" size=2>Verwijderen</th>
    </tr>

    <%
    'response.end
        iPrvStatus=-1
        Do While Not rst.EOF      
            if iPrvStatus<>rst("status") then
            %>
            <tr bgcolor="#00C080"><th colspan=10><font color="white" face="Verdana, Arial" size=2><%=rst("statusomschrijving")%></font></th></tr>
            <%
                iPrvStatus=rst("status")

            end if

            ' Toggle the line color every other line        
            ToggleLine=ToggleLine * -1
            if ToggleLine=1 then
    %>
       **SOME MORE CODE AND HTML**





    </table>
    </body>
</HTML>
<%

closeconn con

end if


if request.querystring("do")="klant" then


**SOME ASP CODE FUNCTIONS AND ACTIONS**


end if


%>
```

**The (CSS - saved as .css) code:**

```
input{ 
text-align:right; 
}

#element_to_pop_up { 
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px 5px #999;
    color: #111;
    display: none;
    min-width: 450px;
    min-height: 180px;
    padding: 25px;
}

.b-close {
border-radius: 7px;
font: bold 131% sans-serif;
padding: 0 6px 2px;
background-color: #2b91af;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
position: absolute;
right: -7px;
top: -7px;
}
.b-close:hover {
background-color: #1e1e1e;
}   

.StyleInkoopbedrag{
width: 55%; 
}

.StyleOmschrijving, .StyleOmschrijving:hover{
width: 85%; 
}

.StyleKLant{
width: 87.5%;       
}

.NieuweRegelVerstuur:hover {
background-color: green;    
}

.NieuweRegelVerstuur{
position: absolute;
background-image: url("/images/OK.png");
margin-left: 1%;
width: 6%;
background-position: center;
text-align: center;
background-color: white;
color: white;
border: 1px solid black;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-size: 100%;
border-radius: 10px;
} 

.hoverEffect{
display: inline;
position: relative;
}
.hoverEffect:hover:after{
background: #333;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
border-radius: 5px;
bottom: 26px;
color: #fff;
content: attr(title);
left: 20%;
padding: 5px 15px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 98;
width: 280px;
}

.hoverEffect:hover:before{
border: solid;
border-color: #333 transparent;
border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
bottom: 20px;
content: "";
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 99;
}
```

-----**UPDATE**-----

**The frameset.asp code:**

```
<!--#include file="tools.asp"-->

Session.Timeout=240

if session("loginok")<>TRUE AND Checklocal<>TRUE then
    response.redirect("login.asp")
end if

%>
<html>

<head>
<title>OPSWEB</title>
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 4.0">
<meta name="ProgId" content="FrontPage.Editor.Document">
</head>

<frameset rows="52,22,*" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0">
  <frame name="header" scrolling="no" noresize target="contents" src="header.asp" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
  <frame name="subheader" target="main" src="statusbar.asp" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" noresize>
  <frameset cols="120,*">
    <frame name="contents" target="main" src="menu.asp?menu=blank" marginwidth="8" marginheight="16" scrolling="auto" noresize>
    <frame name="main" src="showpage.asp?page=intro" scrolling="auto">
  </frameset>
  <noframes>
  <body>

  <p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</p>

  </body>
  </noframes>
</frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: I see no mention of `<frameset>` in the provided code, struggling to understand what you are doing and indeed what the issue is.

Comment: If you are adding the css stylesheet into the page containing the `<frameset>` don't expect the pages contained within the frames to inherit the css it doesn't work like that, you have to specify the `<link rel="stylesheet">` line in each page that needs to use the css styles. In fact defining it in the page with the `<frameset>` is pointless as a `<frameset>` contains no elements to style.

Comment: @Lankymart Indeed Lankymart, after posting this and finding out what is porbably causing it during my typing i went to search for the frameset. It seems that the frameset.asp is a webpage.  That uses some kind of generator and other frameset attributes which I am not familiar to. I posted the frameset.asp code in the original post as an update. P.S. My created webpage doesn't have any reference to the frameset but I am guessing it is being referenced automatically in the menu page which contains the link to my webpage, just thinking out loud now.

Comment: A `<frameset>` is just a shell to contain *separate* HTML pages, these *separate* pages all need there *own* stylesheets definitions, they can be the same definition or different ones the key is they need the definition not the `<frameset>` page.

Comment: Is `http://ops.van-hulten.com` in the `<link>` the current domain if so you don't need to explicitly define it in the `href` just use a relative like so `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleVoorraadlijst.css">` *(also no need for `</link>` when declaring external css links)*.

Comment: But if I am not mistaken my created webpage does have its own stylesheet definition right now? So how could I get it foxed? Yep //ops~ is the current domain, changed the href of the stylesheet and the closing tag of link. Will also do some more research on the frameset.

Comment: Why do you want to use frames at all?  You could use the `include file` directive for your menu and your status bar.  Web designers generally stopped using frames around 1998, and your meta tag saying the page was written with Front Page v4 suggests that your code probably dates back to them

Comment: @John Yep I know, like I said before the main website wasn't build by me. I will change the frameset structure but not anytime soon. But if it is to much of a hassle I will just directly put the css in the asp page or include a asp page which contains the css.